# Monotonicity Theorem of inverse Kazhdan Lusztig polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, coxeter-groups, kazhdan-lusztig

Let $P_{x,w}$ and $Q_{x,w}$ be the Kazhdan Lusztig polynomial and the inverse Kazhdan Lusztig polynomial of Coxeter group $W$, respectively. i.e., $\sum_{x\le y\le z}(-1)^{\ell(y)-\ell(x)}P_{x,y}(q)Q_{y,z}(q)=\delta_{x,z}$.

Let $W$ be a crystallographic Coxeter group. Then the paper **Anders Bjorner and Torsten Ekedahl --- On the shape of Bruhat intervals** shows that:[image]

This result has been proven by interpretating the coefficients of $P_{x,w}$ in terms of the dimension of the fibre of the cohomology of the intersection complex for $\overline{X_z}$ at a point of $X_x$.

When $W$ is finite, it is well-known that $Q_{x,w}(q)=P_{w_0w,w_0x}(q)$. So the Theorem 4.2 can be translated into the following:

> Let $x\le y\le z$ in a **finite** crystallographic Coxeter group. Then $Q^{i}_{x,z}\ge Q^{i}_{x,y}$.
>
> I would like to know whether we can drop the condition "**finite**". In other words, can we prove the monotonicity Theorem for $Q_{x,w}$ for infinite "Weyl groups", say, affine Weyl group, by using combinatorics or interpretation of dimension of the fibre of some cohomology or any other methods?

Personally, I prefer to have some elementary combinatorics method (e.g. using Theorem 4.2, together with some combinatorical relationship between $P_{x,w}$ and $Q_{x,w}$). But any doable methods are welcome.

Comment: As for "any other methods", probably the most powerful tool for understanding Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials for general Coxeter groups is the Soergel bimodules developed by Elias-Williamson. (Although for the case of *affine Weyl groups*, there is still geometry, so that case might be addressable via cohomology, etc.)

Comment: Do you have any references about the interpretation of the coefficients of the inverse Kazhdan Lusztig polynomial in terms of geometry? As my best knowledge, I just read some papers about the geometrical interpretation of coefficients of the Kazhdan Lusztig polynomial.

Comment: No, I don't know about this inverse polynomials, sorry.